# Different icon for each virtual desktop in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, virtualdesktop

I want to put an icon for each of my virtual desktops in KDE. Currently pager widget allows me to select a name for each virtual desktop but there is no option to put an icon for each one.

**EDIT**: I want something like this image from [Chris Titus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ymx7Z19mwAU) but I don't want to install window manager. What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found something near. Not completely what I wanted but good for now. [Here](https://github.com/wsdfhjxc/virtual-desktop-bar) is the repo in github.